# multiple typedef for same type in c

Tags: typedef

I have seen multiple typedef for same type in c

```
typedef struct i_data
{
    uint32 size;
    uint8 *data;
} I_DATA, *I_DATA_PTR;


typedef I_DATA I_TEMP;

typedef I_DATA *I_TEMP_PTR;

typedef I_DATA I_SEARCH_TEMP;

typedef I_DATA *I_SEARCH_PTR;
```

is it possible? How compiler distinguish all this typedef definition

Answer (score 4):

yes, it's not problem. you are basically saying that they are all identical.. :)

I_DATA and I_TEMP and I_SEARCH_TEMP are the same thing, typedefs of the i_data struct.

I_DATA_PTR and I_TEMP_PTR and I_SEARCH_PTR are the same thing, pointers to a typedef of the i_data struct.

If they are all the same, in theory why does the compiler need to tell them apart?

It's a little like a person that has a name and a nickname, it might not be the same name but it's still the same person ;)

Comment: I think there is no need of typedef in case of I_DATA_PTR and I_TEMP_PTR and I_SEARCH_PTR

Comment: there is no need for what? you can also write is as I_DATA* pData, true, but still it's sometimes clearer to write DATA_I_PTR...sometimes in code it's also about clarity..

Answer (score -3):

Sure is possible! I couldn't tell you exactly how the compiler figures this out... I have never read into the inner workings of compilers. I do know that multiple type definitions for the same type are not a problem!